# Object type in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am defining a mongoose schema and definition is as follows:

```
   inventoryDetails: {
        type: Object,
        required: true

    },
    isActive:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false
    }
```

I  tried "Object" type and I am seeing my data is getting saved successfully. When I changed type to array, the save is failing.

**Sample Data:**

```
{
    "inventoryDetails" : { 
        "config" : { 
            "count" : { 
                "static" : { "value" : "123" }, 
                "dataSource" : "STATIC" 
            }, 
            "title" : { 
                "static" : { "value" : "tik" }, 
                "dataSource" : "STATIC" 
            } 
        }, 
        "type" : "s-card-with-title-count" 
    } 
}
```

"Object" type is not one of the types that mongoose allows. But, how it is being supported ?

Comment: What exactly fails for you? Did you check out the documentation. Object type is supported. Array is supported as well. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Comment: yes, I went through the documentation and the following are supported. String,Number,Date,Buffer,Boolean,Mixed,Objectid,Array.                           Where is Object mentioned? And nothing is failing. Just wanted to know whether mongoose implicitly supports javascript datatypes

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You have two options to get your `Object` in the db:

#### 1. Define it by yourself

```
let YourSchema = new Schema({
  inventoryDetails: {
    config: {
      count: {
        static: {
          value: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
          },
          dataSource: {
            type: String
          }
        }
      }
    },
    myType: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  title: {
    static: {
      value: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
      },
      dataSource: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Take a look at my real code:

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({
  //...
  statuses: {
    online: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    },
    verified: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    banned: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  //...
})
```

This option gives you the ability to define the object's data structure.

If you want a flexible object data structure, see the next one.

#### 2. Use the default `Schema.Types.Mixed` type

Example taken from the [doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html):

```
let YourSchema = new Schema({
  inventoryDetails: Schema.Types.Mixed
})

let yourSchema = new YourSchema;

yourSchema.inventoryDetails = { any: { thing: 'you want' } }

yourSchema.save()
```

Comment: Very good demo. Schema is easy to understand as a class definition. But after reading the Mongoose doc, I'm still not getting `SchemaType`, sounds like schema of the schema. Also `path`.

Comment: Great answer. Is there a way to mark the entire object as "required". i.e. "statuses" object itself is required?

Comment: `{type: Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true}` instead of `Schema.Types.Mixed` in the second example

Comment: What about when we had to make this object unique?

Answer (score 9):

**Mongoose 5**

An "anything goes" SchemaType. Mongoose will not do any casting on mixed paths. You can define a mixed path using ***Schema.Types.Mixed*** or by passing an empty object literal. The following are equivalent.

```
const Any = new Schema({ any: {} });
const Any = new Schema({ any: Object });
const Any = new Schema({ any: Schema.Types.Mixed });
const Any = new Schema({ any: mongoose.Mixed });
```

For your current schema you can use the next example:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const inventorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  inventoryDetails: {
    type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Mixed,
    required: true
  },
  isActive:{
    type: Boolean,
    default:false
  }
})

const inventory = await inventorySchema.create({
  inventoryDetails: { 
    config: { 
      count: { 
        static: { value: '123' }, 
        dataSource: 'STATIC' 
      }, 
      title: { 
        static: { value: 'tik' }, 
        dataSource: 'STATIC' 
      } 
    }, 
    type: 's-card-with-title-count' 
  }
})

console.log(inventory)
```

Comment: Error line 5 of second code
type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Mixed, -> type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,

Answer (score 1):

From the mongoose docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#what-is-a-schematype

...//
anything: Schema.Types.Mixed
//...

Mixed is an "anything goes" schema type. The following are equivalent.

```
const Any = new Schema({ any: {} });
const Any = new Schema({ any: Object });
const Any = new Schema({ any: Schema.Types.Mixed });
const Any = new Schema({ any: mongoose.Mixed });
```

So, I think that's why setting type:Object worked.