# Mongoose query using Javascript Object vs Javascript Map

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose model that has a field called timeLimit which is an Object

```
timeLimit: {
  type: Object,
  // of: Date,
},
```

If I try to find documents in this collection using the following query

```
const docs = await Model.find({
    'timeLimit.end': {
      $gt: moment().utc(),
    },
  });
```

I get no result, despite the fact that there are valid values to be returned. However, if I change the field in the model to match a Map of Dates...

```
timeLimit: {
  type: Map,
  of: Date,
},
```

The query returns the valid values of this query.

My question is, why is the query invalid when using the Object mongoose type if MongoDB doesn't even have the Map type, only the Object type?

[image: Types shown in Mongo Compass]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object type in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42019679/object-type-in-mongoose)

Comment: Not quite. It does not cover why fields in an object can't be indexed, but fields in a Map can.